# How to pass multiple operator properties via UI layout?

Tags: scripting, python

Basically, I want to have a single operator which can do multiple things, based on some attributes values.

```
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    # (...)
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("my.button", text="Button text")

class MY_BUTTON_OT_Button(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.button"
    bl_description = "Button description"
    bl_label = "Button"
    foo = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    bar = bpy.props.BoolProperty()

    if bar:
        # Do something with foo
    else:
        # Do something else :P
```

I know how to set **one** attribute, like so:

```
    row.operator("my.button", text="Button text").foo=5
```

But what about multiple arguments?
I tried several things that didn't worked, like (e.g.):

- With `setattr()`:
  <s>`row.operator("my.button", text="Button text").setattr(foo=5,bar=True)`</s>
- With a custom method `setVal()` in the operator class:
  <s>`row.operator("my.button", text="Button text").setVal(foo=5,bar=True)`</s>

Maybe I must use a single `EnumProperty`? I hope to avoid this, so my question is:
**Is it possible to pass multiple custom arguments** to set attributes in an operator class? And if yes, **how** ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There may be other ways, but that's the easiest. Instead of using `operator()`'s return value (an [`OperatorProperties`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.OperatorProperties.html)) right away, capture it in a variable, and assign them there:

```
props = row.operator("my.button", text="Button text")
props.foo = 5
props.bar = "Bar"
props.baz = True
```