# How can a parameter be passed from one operator to another?

Tags: python, scripting

I used a python template to create a menu which is populated by the names of files from the text editor:

```
class AnimMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Anim Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_anim_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        for txt in bpy.data.texts:
            if txt.name[-4:] =='.txt':
                layout.operator("object.anim_operator", text=txt.name).text_name = txt.name # from here
```

Another operator should receive the filename as a parameter

```
class AnimOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.anim_operator"
    bl_label = "Pose Anim Operator"

    text_name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="anim_text_name") # to there

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        txt = bpy.data.texts[ text ].as_string()
        main(context, text_name)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I wasn't able to use this technique:
[How to set multiple custom attributes to operator class when called in UI layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-set-multiple-custom-attributes-to-operator-class-when-called-in-ui-layout)

```
props = layout.operator("object.anim_operator", text=txt.name)
props.text_name = txt.name
```

leads to:

AttributeError: 'OBJECT_OT_anim_operator' object has no attribute 'text_name'

Comment: The snippet actually seems to work. http://www.pasteall.org/52716/python

Comment: I don't know very much about Blender scripting, but I do know a bit of Python. I don't see "OBJECT_OT_anim_operator" anywhere in your code; the example you linked to defined a similarly named class. In both of your classes, the variable `txt` is initialized only in a method within the class. I'm a bit rusty when it comes to coding, though, so perhaps this is all fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the `self` keyword to access the variable in the invoked operator (basic python, ouch!)

```
class AnimOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.anim_operator"
    bl_label = "Pose Anim Operator"

    text_name : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="anim_text_name")
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        print("invoked script name=%s" % self.text_name ) # <<- self.
```