# Where to find correct syntax for operator in Blender API manual?

Tags: python, interface

I have an issue finding the correct documentation online.

**Example:**

CTRL + A calls the following command:

```
bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name="VIEW3D_MT_object_apply")
```

And a selection option reads out the following command:

```
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False)
```

**Solution:**

Now by trial and error I found out that if you want to call an operator it has to be formatted the following way:

```
row.operator("wm.call_menu", text="Apply Tans").name="VIEW3D_MT_object_apply"
row.operator("object.transform_apply", text="Apply Rot").rotation=True
```

name and rotation have to come after the operator closing bracket to pass that information to the operator.

Where can you in the Blender Python API find this information? I searched for it but do not find anything about the correct syntax.

Comment: duplicate ? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2515/5113

Comment: I read this earlier and this option works by first generating a class that can execute the complete bpy command. Then command name is given to the button to operate/ execute.  I am more interested in a solution that is only one line long - if that is actually possible.

Comment: the one line solution is working fine check your full script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs have this information if you know what you're looking for.

[http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/.../wm.call_menu](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=wm.call_menu#bpy.ops.wm.call_menu)

In this case *TextEditor > Templates > Python > UI Menu* has a working example of how to trigger a specific menu

The UI source is often the most comprehensive documentation. For example *space_view3d.py*'s `class VIEW3D_MT_mirror(Menu)` shows how to pass properties to an operator. As you have now seen

```
props = layout.operator("transform.mirror", text="Z Global")
props.constraint_axis = (False, False, True)
props.constraint_orientation = 'GLOBAL'
```

Here both `constraint_axis` and `constraint_orientation` are passed as values to `bpy.ops.transform.mirror` as soon as the button is pressed.