# Python Geometry Node Inputs properties

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

I have a bunch of geometry nodes inputs exposed on a UI panel. I used the layout prop to do so

```
gm = object.modifiers.get("nodes")

col.prop(gm, '["Input_13"]',  text="Min_Size")
col.prop(gm, '["Input_14"]',  text="Max_Size")
col.prop(gm, '["Input_10"]',   text="Offset")
```

I want to have the ability to set a min max values and also to put an update function for each property.

How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass multiple operator properties via UI layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-pass-multiple-operator-properties-via-ui-layout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prop function returns the item it used.  You can modify the state of that of item.  Change your col.prop to something like

```
prop = col.prop(gm, '["Input_13"]',  text="Min_Size")
prop.min = -3.0e-38
prop.max = 3.0e-38
prop.hard_min = -3.0e-38
prop.hard_max = 3.0e-38
```

et cetera  if you want to change the min and max values.  You would of course replace my numeric values with whatever ones you wanted to use.

Comment: Good to know thanks , and i found out that geometry nodes inputs do have min max values for floats and integers on the group panel

Comment: The props are the same kind as any other so that means they use things like `StringProperty` and `FloatProperty`, so the floats will have exactly the same set of instance variables as a `FloatProperty`.

Comment: You're very welcome.  I look forward to seeing what you accomplish.

Comment: I have trouble understanding this one. As I understand it `layout.prop` returns `None`. Did I miss something ? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop

Comment: @Gorgious I think that is a documentation bug. IIRC I did test the code before I posted.