# correct syntax required to add size AND location when using row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")

Tags: python, mesh

New to Blender and python, but not programming.
I have been following a youtube series which creates a panel in the 3D window.
The author was using blender 2.8 and I have 3.3.12.

I want to create a mesh cube at location .5, .5, .5 and with size=1
With the current code as follows, I can only either add size or location but not both.
Is there a way to do this?

Here is my current code;

```
bl_info = {
    "name":  "ObjectAdder",
    "author":  "ezywingman",
    "version":  (1, 0, 0),
    "blender":  (3, 3, 12),
    "location":  "View3d > Add > Mesh > ObjectAdder",
    "description": "Example",
    "warning":  "",
    "doc_url":  "",
    "category":  "Add Mesh",
}   


# Load the Python language into the system
import bpy

class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label       = "ObjectAdder"
    bl_idname      = "PT_TestPanel"
    # set where the panel will reside
    bl_space_type  = 'VIEW_3D'
    # select the region where the panel will reside
    # in this instance 'UI' is the side of the 3D panel
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    # place in a current tab, or create a new one
    # in this instance it's a new one
    bl_category    = "Object_Creation"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row    = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Add an object", icon = 'CUBE')
        row    = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", icon='CUBE').location=(.5,.5,.5)
        row    = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", icon='SPHERE').location=(1,1,1)
        row    = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.text_add", icon = 'FILE_FONT', text="Font Button")
        row    = layout.row()
                 
class PanelA(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label       = "Scaling"
    bl_idname      = "PT_PanelA"
    bl_space_type  = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category    = "Object creation"
    bl_parent_id = 'PT_TestPanel'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        row    = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Select an option to scale your object", icon = 'FONT_DATA')
        row    = layout.row()
        row.operator("transform.resize")
        col = layout.column() 
        col.prop(obj, "scale")

class PanelB(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label       = "Specials"
    bl_idname      = "PT_PanelB"
    bl_space_type  = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category    = "Object creation"
    bl_parent_id = 'PT_TestPanel'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row    = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Select a special Option", icon = 'COLOR_BLUE')
        row    = layout.row()                
        row.operator("object.shade_smooth", icon='MOD_SMOOTH', text= "Set Smooth Shading")
        row.operator("object.subdivision_set")
        row    = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.modifier_add")
        
        
        
 #      
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelA)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PanelB)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PanelA)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PanelB)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

```
now sorted using this updated part if the code thanks to 'Gorgious'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row    = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Add an object", icon = 'CUBE')
        row    = layout.row()
        op = row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", icon='CUBE')
        op.location=(.5,.5,.5)
        op.size = (1)
        row     = layout.row()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass multiple operator properties via UI layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-pass-multiple-operator-properties-via-ui-layout)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see how to impliment that in my code.
Very green on using OOP (classes etc).

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Gorgious, I re-write part of your code below:

```
def draw(self, context):
    .... etc
    row    = layout.row()
    op = row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", icon='CUBE')
    op.location=(.5,.5,.5)
    row    = layout.row()
    ... etc
```

In other words (from the linked solution), operator() returns it's object identity, so you can then use "op.another_method()" to operate on the object stored in variable "op".

Comment: That's it. 
Many thanks, I think I get it now.
New code now looks like;

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row    = layout.row()
        row.label(text = "Add an object", icon = 'CUBE')
        row    = layout.row()
        op = row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", icon='CUBE')
        op.location=(.5,.5,.5)
        op.size = (1)
        row     = layout.row()